# Java unterminated object error when making JSON

Tags: java, json

I'm trying to create a JSON object that looks like:

```
{
  "values": {
    "barcode": "{"title":"611269991000grant"}"
  }
}
```

Note that the value of barcode is only a string. Here's what I'm writing:

```
// title = 611269991000grant
params = new JSONObject("{\"values\": {\"barcode\":" + "\"{\"title\":\"" +  title + "\"}\" } }");
```

The problem however is that this will throw an exception saying

`Unterminated object at character 26 of {"values": {"barcode":"{"title":"611269991000grant"}" } }`

Anyone know what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Look at the syntax highlighting.  Your JSON doesn't make sense.

Comment: This isn't valid JSON, that's why it isn't working.

Comment: I'm trying to still contain `"` within the string value of barcode, how can I do that then? I tried using \

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution to my problem:

```
String jsonobj = "{\\\"title\\\":\\\"" +  title + "\\\"}";
params = new JSONObject("{\"values\": {\"barcode\":\"" + jsonobj + "\"} }");
```

I needed to double escape because the value of barcode is sent over a stream and I still needed it to be in JSON format. So my program now reads the JSON object as

```
{"values":{"barcode":"{\"title\":\"611269991000,grant\"}"}}
```

and the barcode value is sent to the stream and read by the webapp as

```
{"title":"611269991000,grant"}
```

pseudo JSON! I forgot to mention that the barcode value can only contain a string, which is why I was trying to do magic.

Answer (score 0):

That's invalid **JSON**. Change

```
params = new JSONObject("{\"values\": {\"barcode\":" + "\"{\"title\":\"" +  title + "\"}\" } }");
```

to

```
params = new JSONObject("{\"values\": {\"barcode\":" + "{\"title\":\"" +  title + "\"} } }");
```

So that your **JSON** would finally be:

```
{
  "values": {
    "barcode": {"title":"611269991000grant"}
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your intent is that the value of `barcode` is a String representation of a document, and not a document ,then

```
"{"title":"611269991000grant"}"
```

is not valid, you either scape the inner double quotes `"` with `\` or you replace the inner double quotes `"` with single quotes `'`

```
{
  "values": {
    "barcode": "{'title':'611269991000grant'}"
  }
}
```

or

```
{
  "values": {
    "barcode": "{\"title\":\"611269991000grant\"}"
  }
}
```